# How to pad cell-arrays in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Does someone know how to pad cell-arrays? For regular (multi-dimensional) arrays, I can use the function

```
   A = padarray(A,dim,value)
```

However it won't accept cells...
Been searching but I can't find anything in the docs or google, thought I'd ask before trying to reprogram padarray() to accept cells... if someone knows how to do this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Convert to regular array with `cell2mat`?

Comment: I've modified the padarray() function from the image-processing toolbox to work with cells. There were just a couple calls that didn't accept cells which needed to be replaced (nothing complicated). But since the function is from a copy-righted toolbox, I'm not sure if I can post the 'solution' here... perhaps a veteran can weigh in...

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `cellfun` to apply a function to each cell in a cell array:

```
padize = 2;
A = cellfun( @(x) padarray(x,padsize), A ,'uni', 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to pad the actual cell-array, not what is contained in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure regular Matlab has nothing for cell arrays just like it has nothing for numeric ones (`padarray` belongs to the Image Processing Toolbox). How difficult it is depends on how generic you need it - the basic symmetric empty-padded fixed-number-of-dimensions case is trivial:

```
function y = padcell2d(x, r)
y = cell(size(x) + r.*2);
y(r+1:end-r, r+1:end-r) = x;
end
```

Add complexity as required.

---

Since it was fun thinking of the simplest way to handle arbitrary dimensions, here's a really hacky way of n-dimensional symmetric empty padding without loops (tested on Octave):

```
function x = padcell(x, r)
if any(r>0) && ~any(r<0)
  if isscalar(r)    % otherwise, assume it's a value-per-dimension vector
    r = repmat(r, 1, ndims(x));
  end
  sz = num2cell(size(x) + 2*r);
  x{sz{:}} = [];     % hooray for comma-separated lists!
  x = circshift(x, r);
end
end
```

Comment: Agreed :). Where I'm having trouble is making it rather general: I have n-dimensional cell-arrays, loop through each dimension to check if it needs to be padded, and if so, pad it.